# Firebase Cloud Messaging without hosting (Web/JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

When working through the official video tutorial for Firebase Cloud Messaging, I am not able to get a messaging token without hosting the application.

Here is my `app.js` file:

```
/* global firebase */

// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
  apiKey: 'AIzaSyBYfb9HAi_oE-PKqFNkRQcxAgLU-nm8sIE',
  authDomain: 'web-quickstart-c0309.firebaseapp.com',
  databaseURL: 'https://web-quickstart-c0309.firebaseio.com',
  projectId: 'web-quickstart-c0309',
  storageBucket: 'web-quickstart-c0309.appspot.com',
  messagingSenderId: '713880824056'
}
firebase.initializeApp(config)

const messaging = firebase.messaging()
messaging.requestPermission()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Permission granted.')
    return messaging.getToken()
      .then(token => {
        console.log('messaging token test:', token)
        return token
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('messaging error:', error)
      })
  })
  .then(token => {
    console.log('permission token test:', token)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log('permission error:', error)
  })
```

I have a `firebase-messaging-sw.js` file in my root directory.

When I load the `index.html` file directly in my browser and accept the dialog, I receive an undefined value for the token. The full console output is:

```
16:20:35.744 app.js:17 Permission granted.
16:20:35.750 app.js:20 messaging token test: null
16:20:35.751 app.js:28 permission token test: null
```

If I host the application by editing the `firebase.json` file to read:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "./"
  }
}
```

And then run `firebase serve -p 8081`, open `http://localhost:8081`, and accept the dialog, I do receive a token. The full output is:

```
16:23:42.902 app.js:17 Permission granted.
16:23:43.059 app.js:20 messaging token test: eyd1EaFwULQ:APA91bGUZr9fAGcCaYVtXTPjk55AmpWLNdaqGapMa1S1GWTYeJwtJraEKuhAPpSM-v-2xPaSJQgTKRVosTN-0KRPHCccjdRZNDkegtW2HMC_mSbdap9h5TeH7KKQSbN4QrjVmIl7VZlu
16:23:43.060 app.js:28 permission token test: eyd1EaFwULQ:APA91bGUZr9fAGcCaYVtXTPjk55AmpWLNdaqGapMa1S1GWTYeJwtJraEKuhAPpSM-v-2xPaSJQgTKRVosTN-0KRPHCccjdRZNDkegtW2HMC_mSbdap9h5TeH7KKQSbN4QrjVmIl7VZlu
```

Is this a documented constraint? Is there a way to receive a token without hosting the application?

Comment: Is localhost an approved domain in your firebase console settings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FCM work only in pages served by https protocol

as in the [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client)

> The FCM SDK is supported only in pages served over HTTPS. This is due
>   to its use of service workers, which are available only on HTTPS
>   sites. Need a provider? Firebase Hosting is an easy way to get free
>   HTTPS hosting on your own domain.

and if you wonder why localhost work that because pages in localhost work just like they served by https

**so** *Is there a way to receive a token without hosting the application?*

The answer is **No** your page should be served by https protocol

Comment: I'm going crazy I hope you might know the answer. In the same tutorial the guy is using `importScripts()` in the `firebase-messaging-sw.js` service worker but `importScripts()` is undefined. Stack says it only works within a worker. This guy in the tutorial says his app is basic, just an HTML page. How is he using `importScripts()`?

Comment: This is the tutorial which is the same as the original poster, https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client and at the very beginning he covers what app he's using. At 3:38 he uses `importScripts()`

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say this is the exact alternative  but an alternative solution to the problem , you can use the [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/download) , which will provide you with the Https access for alternative way of representing the `localhost` .

So after installing use whatever URL it outputs on the terminal from ngrok in the FCM.

**Note**: ngrok outputs both `http`and `https` URLs, so use Only `Https` . They still map to your local server.